# Not receiving push notifications anymore.

Tags: bug, ios-app

- App Version: 1.6.6.2
- Device: iPhone 6
- OS Version: Version 11.0.2 (Build 15A421)

Comment: Have you checked in the Settings that push notifications are enabled for this app?

Comment: have you updated os recently?